# Botframework Azure Template dependsOn MsTeamsChannel CLI Deployment template validation failed

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cli, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to execute this instruction of Azure CLI:

```
az deployment sub create --name  "ThisIsATest"  --location northeurope
--template-file /Users/muzcateg/Documents/TeaBotframeworkVIP/DeploymentTemplates/template-with-new-rg.json
--parameters appId="7450874d-a8cb-4613-b021-621a34b21bbb" appSecret="ThisIsATest123456789" botId="ThisIsATest" botSku=F0 newAppServicePlanName="ThisIsATestServicePlan" newWebAppName="ThisIsATestWebApp" groupName="ThisIsATestResources" groupLocation="northeurope" newAppServicePlanLocation="northeurope" 
--output json
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
{
    'additionalProperties': {},
    'code': 'InvalidTemplate',
    'message': "Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource '/subscriptions/63c45336-738e-4431-b8cd-21097fd6a9f4/resourceGroups/ThisIsATestResources/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/ThisIsATest/channels/MsTeamsChannel' at line '1' and column '2080' doesn't depend on parent resource '/subscriptions/63c45336-738e-4431-b8cd-21097fd6a9f4/resourceGroups/ThisIsATestResources/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/ThisIsATest'. Please add dependency explicitly using the 'dependsOn' syntax. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.",
    'target': None,
    'details': None,
    'additionalInfo': [{
        'additionalProperties': {},
        'type': 'TemplateViolation',
        'info': {
            'lineNumber': 1,
            'linePosition': 2080,
            'path': 'properties.template.resources[2].resources[0]'
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm using the standard template (template-with-new-rg.json) from the Botframework GIT examples, I have tried a lot of changes to see if I can make it work but with no success.

A colleague of mine is executing the instruction correctly in her PC, She is using CLI 2.7.0, I was using 2.8.0 and I change it to 2.7.0 too, we are supposed to have the same permissions in Azure.

Just in case, this is the template code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "groupLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specifies the location of the Resource Group."
            }
        },
        "groupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specifies the name of the Resource Group."
            }
        },
        "appId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Active Directory App ID, set as MicrosoftAppId in the Web App's Application Settings."
            }
        },
        "appSecret": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Active Directory App Password, set as MicrosoftAppPassword in the Web App's Application Settings."
            }
        },
        "botId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The globally unique and immutable bot ID. Also used to configure the displayName of the bot, which is mutable."
            }
        },
        "botSku": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier of the Bot Service Registration. Acceptable values are F0 and S1."
            }
        },
        "newAppServicePlanName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the App Service Plan."
            }
        },
        "newAppServicePlanSku": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "name": "S1",
                "tier": "Standard",
                "size": "S1",
                "family": "S",
                "capacity": 1
            },
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The SKU of the App Service Plan. Defaults to Standard values."
            }
        },
        "newAppServicePlanLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location of the App Service Plan. Defaults to \"westus\"."
            }
        },
        "newWebAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The globally unique name of the Web App. Defaults to the value passed in for \"botId\"."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "appServicePlanName": "[parameters('newAppServicePlanName')]",
        "resourcesLocation": "[parameters('newAppServicePlanLocation')]",
        "webAppName": "[if(empty(parameters('newWebAppName')), parameters('botId'), parameters('newWebAppName'))]",
        "siteHost": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
        "botEndpoint": "[concat('https://', variables('siteHost'), '/api/messages')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('groupName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('groupLocation')]",
            "properties": {
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "name": "storageDeployment",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('groupName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('groupName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "comments": "Create a new App Service Plan",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
                            "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                            "location": "[variables('resourcesLocation')]",
                            "sku": "[parameters('newAppServicePlanSku')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "comments": "Create a Web App using the new App Service Plan",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "location": "[variables('resourcesLocation')]",
                            "kind": "app",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
                            ],
                            "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
                                "serverFarmId": "[variables('appServicePlanName')]",
                                "siteConfig": {
                                    "appSettings": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                                            "value": "10.14.1"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "MicrosoftAppId",
                                            "value": "[parameters('appId')]"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "MicrosoftAppPassword",
                                            "value": "[parameters('appSecret')]"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "cors": {
                                        "allowedOrigins": [
                                            "https://botservice.hosting.portal.azure.net",
                                            "https://hosting.onecloud.azure-test.net/"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                      {
                        "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
                        "type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices",
                        "name": "[parameters('botId')]",
                        "location": "global",
                        "kind": "bot",
                        "sku": {
                          "name": "[parameters('botSku')]"
                        },
                        "properties": {
                          "name": "[parameters('botId')]",
                          "displayName": "[parameters('botId')]",
                          "endpoint": "[variables('botEndpoint')]",
                          "msaAppId": "[parameters('appId')]",
                          "developerAppInsightsApplicationId": null,
                          "developerAppInsightKey": null,
                          "publishingCredentials": null,
                          "storageResourceId": null
                        },
                        "resources": [
                          {
                            "name": "MsTeamsChannel",
                            "type": "channels",
                            "location": "global",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-07-12",
                            "kind": "bot",
                            "properties": {
                              "channelName": "MsTeamsChannel"
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [
                              "[resourceId('Microsoft.BotService/botServices', parameters('botId'))]"
                            ]
                          }
                        ],
                        "dependsOn": [
                          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webAppName'))]"
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    "outputs": {}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: did you read the error message and try to fix it? honestly, i'd start with moving away from inline template to a linked template, that will probably fix the error in 99.9% of the cases

Comment: Yes I did, and I don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template just works on the old version of de Azure CLI in our case 2.0.7, so after lots of test and reading we end up deploying this JSON file with Azure CLI 2.7.0 and 2.8.0

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "appId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Active Directory App ID, set as MicrosoftAppId in the Web App's Application Settings."
            }
        },
        "appSecret": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Active Directory App Password, set as MicrosoftAppPassword in the Web App's Application Settings. Defaults to \"\"."
            }
        },
        "botId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The globally unique and immutable bot ID. Also used to configure the displayName of the bot, which is mutable."
            }
        },
        "botSku": {
            "defaultValue": "F0",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier of the Bot Service Registration. Acceptable values are F0 and S1."
            }
        },
        "newAppServicePlanName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the new App Service Plan."
            }
        },
        "newAppServicePlanSku": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "name": "S1",
                "tier": "Standard",
                "size": "S1",
                "family": "S",
                "capacity": 1
            },
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The SKU of the App Service Plan. Defaults to Standard values."
            }
        },
        "appServicePlanLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location of the App Service Plan."
            }
        },
        "existingAppServicePlan": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the existing App Service Plan used to create the Web App for the bot."
            }
        },
        "existingAppServicePlanResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the resource group for the existing App Service Plan used to create the Web App for the bot."
            }
        },        
        "newWebAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The globally unique name of the Web App. Defaults to the value passed in for \"botId\"."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "defaultAppServicePlanName": "[if(empty(parameters('existingAppServicePlan')), 'createNewAppServicePlan', parameters('existingAppServicePlan'))]",
        "useExistingAppServicePlan": "[not(equals(variables('defaultAppServicePlanName'), 'createNewAppServicePlan'))]",
        "servicePlanName": "[if(variables('useExistingAppServicePlan'), parameters('existingAppServicePlan'), parameters('newAppServicePlanName'))]",
        "resourcesLocation": "[parameters('appServicePlanLocation')]",
        "webAppName": "[if(empty(parameters('newWebAppName')), parameters('botId'), parameters('newWebAppName'))]",
        "siteHost": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
        "botEndpoint": "[concat('https://', variables('siteHost'), '/api/messages')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Create a new App Service Plan if no existing App Service Plan name was passed in.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "condition": "[not(variables('useExistingAppServicePlan'))]",
            "name": "[variables('servicePlanName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "location": "[variables('resourcesLocation')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('newAppServicePlanSku')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('servicePlanName')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "comments": "Create a Web App using an App Service Plan",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "location": "[variables('resourcesLocation')]",
            "kind": "app",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('servicePlanName'))]"
            ],
            "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('webAppName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('servicePlanName'))]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                            "value": "10.14.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MicrosoftAppId",
                            "value": "[parameters('appId')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MicrosoftAppPassword",
                            "value": "[parameters('appSecret')]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cors": {
                        "allowedOrigins": [
                            "https://botservice.hosting.portal.azure.net",
                            "https://hosting.onecloud.azure-test.net/"
                        ]
                    },
                    "webSocketsEnabled": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices",
            "name": "[parameters('botId')]",
            "location": "global",
            "kind": "bot",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('botSku')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('botId')]",
                "displayName": "[parameters('botId')]",
                "endpoint": "[variables('botEndpoint')]",
                "msaAppId": "[parameters('appId')]",
                "developerAppInsightsApplicationId": null,
                "developerAppInsightKey": null,
                "publishingCredentials": null,
                "storageResourceId": null
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webAppName'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks to all.